# Filtering user-launched applications (Mac OS X)

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, filtering

`NSWorkspace().runningApplications` gives me a complete list of all the applications running, but I want to filter out the ones launched specifically by the user. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something along these lines should help you:

```swift
 let apps = NSWorkspace().runningApplications

 for app in apps {
            print("URL: \(app.executableURL!) App name: \(app.localizedName!)")

            switch app.activationPolicy! {
            case NSApplicationActivationPolicy.Regular:
                println(" Normal app ")
            case NSApplicationActivationPolicy.Accessory:
                println(" Accessory app")
            case NSApplicationActivationPolicy.Prohibited:
                println(" backgound app")
            default:
                println("unknown")
            }
  }
```

Just check for the Regular apps

**Note**: although my answer is maybe clearer to someone without enough exposure to functional programming, [Leonardo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29311522/225503) is more succinct and shows how to use `map` & `filter`

Answer (score 3):

Follow up on Diego's answer, You can use filter and map in conjunction to accomplish what you want. You can filter your array using activationPolicy and in top of that you can map the result to extract the names of your regular running apps.

```
let regularApps = NSWorkspace.shared.runningApplications.filter { $0.activationPolicy == .regular }.compactMap(\.localizedName)

print(regularApps) // "[Finder, Mail, Messages, Preview, Skype, iOS Simulator, iTunes, Photos, Safari, TextEdit, iBooks, System Preferences, QuickTime Player, App Store, Disk Speed Test, Xcode]"
```