# Use NSRunningApplications?

Tags: swift, macos, nsworkspace

I am trying to have my OS X Application detect if a certain program is running but NSRunningApplications isn't working for me. This is my code:

```
import AppKit
class func sharedWorkspace() -> NSWorkspace
{
    var runningApplications: [NSRunningApplications] {get}
}
```

The error I'm getting is

> Expected '{' to start getter definition.

as well as

> Missing return in a function expected to return 'NSWorkspace.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29311522/2303865

Comment: Eric D got it. His code is smoother and makes more sense. Thanks though!

Comment: Man coming back to questions asked when I was first learning to program is trippy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got to use `NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().runningApplications` itself:

```
for app in NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().runningApplications {
    if let name = app.localizedName {
        print(name)
    }
}
```

You can get the running applications names in an array with a simple `map` (or `flatMap` here to manage Optionals):

```
let names = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().runningApplications.flatMap { $0.localizedName }

print(names)
```

Comment: Thanks! Quick question, though. How can I assign the values to an array?

Answer (score 1):

In **Swift 5+** the syntax changed to:

```swift
NSWorkspace.shared.runningApplications
```